# hadoop installation in window 10 path error

Tags: windows, hadoop, hadoop2

I am trying to install Hadoop 2.6 in Windows 10, while doing that i'm getting below error

```
C:\hadoop-2.6.2\bin>hadoop -version
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set.
Please update C:\hadoop-2.6.2\conf\hadoop-env.cmd
'-Xmx512m' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: what is the location of `winutil.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it can be fixed by 2 ways.

1. check your environment variable, if JAVA_HOME setup for the user or not and path setup correctly or not.
   Please remove system JAVA_HOME and setup for user.
2. Go to command line and setup Java Home and Path.

   > set JAVA_HOME = your jdk home directory

> set PATH = %JAVA_HOME%/bin

Comment: on windows, path separator is '\' so it should be "set PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin"